# How to use libraries (*.a files) in C++ when using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, static, libraries

So recently I started programming C++ again. I want to learn how to use Cmake properly and also start writing proper tests for my hobby projects from now on.

I basically just want to integrate GTest in my Project. I set up a TestProject directory and did the following:

1. cloned the [GTest repository](https://github.com/google/googletest.git)
2. build the code in the googletest repositroy with cmake
3. copied the `googletest/build/lib` directory to `TestProject/`
4. copied the `googletest/include` directory to `TestProject/`

Now when I try to use cmake, I get the following error when linking:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ./libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): in function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<testing::TestPartResultReporterInterface*>::~ThreadLocal()':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEED2Ev[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEED5Ev]+0x24): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/usr/bin/ld: gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEED2Ev[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEED5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): in function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<std::vector<testing::internal::TraceInfo, std::allocator<testing::internal::TraceInfo> > >::~ThreadLocal()':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEED2Ev[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEED5Ev]+0x24): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/usr/bin/ld: gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEED2Ev[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEED5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): in function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<std::vector<testing::internal::TraceInfo, std::allocator<testing::internal::TraceInfo> > >::GetOrCreateValue() const':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE16GetOrCreateValueEv[_ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE16GetOrCreateValueEv]+0x25): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/usr/bin/ld: gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE16GetOrCreateValueEv[_ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE16GetOrCreateValueEv]+0x88): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): in function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<testing::TestPartResultReporterInterface*>::CreateKey()':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE9CreateKeyEv[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE9CreateKeyEv]+0x27): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): in function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<std::vector<testing::internal::TraceInfo, std::allocator<testing::internal::TraceInfo> > >::CreateKey()':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE9CreateKeyEv[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE9CreateKeyEv]+0x27): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): in function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<testing::TestPartResultReporterInterface*>::GetOrCreateValue() const':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv[_ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv]+0x25): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/usr/bin/ld: gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv[_ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv]+0x88): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
```

The files in my project directory are:

`TestProject/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(TestGoogleTest)

set(ROOT_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set(SRC "${ROOT_DIR}/src")
set(LIB "${ROOT_DIR}/lib")
set(INCLUDE "${ROOT_DIR}/include")

link_directories("${LIB}")
include_directories("${INCLUDE}")

message("INCLUDE PATH: ${INCLUDE}")

set(SOURCES "${SRC}/main.cpp" "${INCLUDE}/gtest/gtest.h")

add_executable(main "${SOURCES}")
target_link_libraries(main libgtest.a)
```

`TestProject/src/main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

It works fine if I compile it manually with the systems gtest with the command

```sh
g++ src/main.cpp -o main -lgtest
```

I would be very happy to understand what causes the problem :)

Comment: You need to also link with libpthread

Comment: Unless the path `TestProject/libgtest.a` is valid, the `target_link_libraries()` command probably won't know to find this library. You should provide the **full** path to the library instead. Even better, just use CMake's [`FindGtest`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGTest.html) module to locate GTest on your machine, instead of manually copying everything..

Comment: @user253751 This resulted in yet another compiler error of the same kind. I could keep on including all the libraries, but I have a feeling this solution might be to messy. Thanks anyways

Comment: @squareskittles I tried using the full path, which didn't work. The link to FindGtest you posted was very helpful however. This works great and looks very lean in the CMakeLists.txt.

Just a last question: Let's say I want to include another library which is not libgtest. Would the rough methodology I used for libgtest work in another scenario?

Comment: @stuckprogrammersad I'm glad it's working. CMake has very many built-in Find Modules like this. If you want to include other libraries this way, you can check the list [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/tree/master/Modules) to see if a Find Module for that library exists. Your other library may also ship with a CMake package configuration file, for which you can also use the `find_package()` command.

Comment: @stuckprogrammersad If your code is now working, I encourage you to create a quick Answer post, answering your own question, showing the modified code. This way, future visitors can understand how you fixed the problem, and can learn from your post.

Comment: @squareskittles Thanks! I'll do so. Also thanks for the sources for further reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the answer @squareskittles proposed. My `CMakeLists.txt` is now also way cleaner and looks like this

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(TestGoogleTest)

enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

set(ROOT_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set(SRC "${ROOT_DIR}/src")

set(SOURCES "${SRC}/main.cpp")

add_executable(test "${SOURCES}")
target_link_libraries(test GTest::GTest GTest::Main)
```

I'm sure the answer provided by @SALEH is solving the problem the way I wanted to solve it first. I haven't tried it out though.

Thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 2):

### Short Explanation

In your `CMakeLists.txt`

- You have not set flags for `c++11` which GoogleTest requires
- You have not linked `pthread` library, therefore GoogleTest can't find the definitions related to this

### Long Explanation

Although there are some better ways to achieve the same thing, I am going to stick with the build policy that you are conforming for your application.

I am assuming the following directory structure

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── gtest
│       ├── gtest-death-test.h
│       ├── gtest.h
│       ├── gtest-matchers.h
│       ├── gtest-message.h
│       ├── gtest-param-test.h
│       ├── gtest_pred_impl.h
│       ├── gtest-printers.h
│       ├── gtest_prod.h
│       ├── gtest-spi.h
│       ├── gtest-test-part.h
│       ├── gtest-typed-test.h
│       └── internal
│           ├── custom
│           │   ├── gtest.h
│           │   ├── gtest-port.h
│           │   ├── gtest-printers.h
│           │   └── README.md
│           ├── gtest-death-test-internal.h
│           ├── gtest-filepath.h
│           ├── gtest-internal.h
│           ├── gtest-param-util.h
│           ├── gtest-port-arch.h
│           ├── gtest-port.h
│           ├── gtest-string.h
│           └── gtest-type-util.h
├── libs
│   ├── libgmock.a
│   ├── libgmock_main.a
│   ├── libgtest.a
│   └── libgtest_main.a
├── main
└── src
    └── main.cpp
```

Then I invoke `g++` directly from shell typing the following line (trying to mimick your call strategy)

`g++ src/main.cpp --std=c++11 -o main -Iinclude -Llib -lgtest -pthread`

**Meaning of the flags**

- GoogleTest needs `c++11` compliant compiler, therefore we need the `--std=c++11` flag
- `-Iinclude` is required to use headers under `include` without specifying the `include` directory name
- `-Llib` specifies the path in where `gtest` library exists
- `pthread` is required to use GoogleTest, although it is possible to build GoogleTest such that it can be used single-threaded manner

It works without causing any issues

Then I mimicked your `CMakeLists.txt` and added some few things which are highlighted below (working without any issue)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(TestGoogleTest)
# added the line below to find libraries for threading
find_package(Threads)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(ROOT_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set(SRC "${ROOT_DIR}/src")
set(LIB "${ROOT_DIR}/lib")

# added the line below to enable c++11 features
set(INCLUDE "${ROOT_DIR}/include") 

link_directories("${LIB}")
include_directories("${INCLUDE}")

message("INCLUDE PATH: ${INCLUDE}")

set(SOURCES "${SRC}/main.cpp" "${INCLUDE}/gtest/gtest.h")

add_executable(main "${SOURCES}")

# modified the line below to express link dependency on gtest and thread libraries
# lib prefix can be omitted here
target_link_libraries(main gtest ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

Answer (score 0):

g++ -o main -lgtest src/main.cpp "libname".a

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your answer, but this does not use CMake as the question asks.